# SocialAuthenticationFilter and dynamic redirect_url

Tags: oauth, spring-security, facebook-social-plugins, spring-social

I'm using spring social 1.1.2 and I would like to redirect the users to a specific page after the authentication with the provider.

Since SocialAuthenticationFilter reacts to "/auth/facebook", I was expecting to be able to add a request param like "/auth/facebook?id=123", but the spring filter react as a rejected authentication.

Is there any way to receive back a param in the redirect_url from the provider?

Maybe it's just conceptually wrong because this approach should be used for the login process on the application and the redirect_url should be constant..

Unfortunately, the login page is expecting a param to identify the "area" on witch the user wants to login. I would prefer not to use cookies/session because there is no guarantees that the "WHATEVER_PARAM_KEY" get overridden before the user click "confirm" on the social provider (for example he tries to login to a different area of the app).

Is there any way to carry information across the authentication process with the social provider?